# basic_streambuf does not set eof bit when using setp

Tags: c++, ostream

I'm trying to use a std::ostream backed by a buffer that I own.

When using setp to have the std::basic_streambuf to us my buffer, everything works fine expect that I would have expected the eof to be set when writing more bytes that were allocated for my buffer. The fail and bad bits are being set while the eof bit is not.

Is this the expected behavior?

If not, how can I get the eof bit to be set?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <streambuf>

template <typename char_type>
struct OStreamBufWrapper : public std::basic_streambuf<char_type, std::char_traits<char_type> >
{
    OStreamBufWrapper(char_type* buffer, std::streamsize bufferLength)
    {
        // set the "put" pointer the start of the buffer and record its length.
        this->setp(buffer, buffer + bufferLength);
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int bufsize = 10;
    char *buf = new char[bufsize];

    OStreamBufWrapper<char> ost(buf, bufsize);
    std::ostream sb(&ost);

    char i = 0;
    while ( 1 )
    {
        sb.write(&i, 1);

        if (!sb.good())
        {
            if (sb.fail())
                std::cout << "fail\n";
            if (sb.bad())
                std::cout << "bad\n";
            if (sb.eof())
                std::cout << "eof\n";

            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    delete [] buf;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no EOF in an output stream.

Comment: When you do a large write the stream writes the first buffer's worth, then the next, then the next, and so on.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, there is no EOF in an output stream? 

Why does my above code compile? sb.eof()